# What is the origin of Pasporta Servo?

Tags: culture

I've never used this service so far, but I have heard about the "Esperanto couchsurfing", much older than the modern couchsurfing, from friends that have been in Esperantujo for much longer. How did Pasporta Servo begin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pasporta Servo was well-established when my wife and I started learning Esperanto in 1997. I still have my first "pasporto" from 1998, with 871 addresses in it. It continued to grow over the next several years.

It is/was a service of TEJO. The *Vikipedio* article contains the following about its history.

*La adreslibro Pasporta Servo estas eldonaĵo de Tutmonda Esperantista Junulara Organizo (TEJO). La unua ideo pri la tiel nomata "Programo Pasporto" aperis en 1966, kaj estis propono de Ruben Feldman-Gonzalez el Argentino. Pasporta Servo laŭ la nuna sistemo aperis unuafoje en 1974, kun 40 gastigantoj, sub gvido de Jeanne-Marie Cash el Francio. Ambaŭ pioniroj daŭre estas gastigantoj de Pasporta Servo. Inter 1995 kaj 2008 ĝia kompilanto estis Derk Ederveen.*

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasporta_Servo

Answer (score 5):

Some more details about Pasporta Servo's early years can be found in this blog article of Ro Sartoro from Argentina, where it was founded as a means to facilitate travel under the military junta: 
http://esperantorondo.blogspot.de/2016/04/1966-2016-pasporta-servo-datrevenas.html

Comment: Lars, so nice to see you here on Stack Exchange! Welcome! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the resource!